# Need to get Type of operation performed on Mail

Tags: outlook-redemption

I want to generate EmailThreading ..

Can some one advise, which field i can use from Redemption to get TypeOf(Replied,Forwared etc..)for given mail chain.

Let's say for the case,

- A send mail to B.
- B forward that mail to C.
- C forward that mail to D.
- D Replied to mail A.

which field of redemption i can use to get Reply,Forward type detail which can be use in generation of Email Threading.

There are few fields i have searched as below,
PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED

PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED, this field having value for last action that mean if B send mail to C, this field having value for Mail of B user, but no value can be found in this field for c user Mail.

Can we capture accurate information of MailType using subject prefix or anyother property using Redemption??

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to look at the `PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID` MAPI property (take a look at the messages with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - I am its author) to figure the reply/forward chain. You can also check out the `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` property to see if the threading is correctly captured there.